# Finder default window

Tags: macos, finder

I have an issue with Finders window sizes. I know that the Finder saves the window size per directory, which REALLY drives me nuts!

I want to set one window size for the Finder. I totally lose it each time a folder opens in a narrow window and I have to adjust the size of the window, the sidebar and all columns before I can start working in my familiar environment...

Is there any way to disable the REALLY bad and ANNOYING behavior?

I know every single answer on google and StackExchange but there does not seem to be a solution.

So know I'm searching for a way to delete the folders window settings so that it might open in default size.

Answer (score 1):

I used this "trick" on Mountain Lion and it worked well for me.

> Create a new folder on the Desktop (CMD+SHIFT+N), open it, select
>   View-View Options (CMD+J), set the window to your desired size and
>   type view (either icon or list view: I prefer the latter), select
>   always open, and then click Use as Defaults button. That should retain
>   your setting and every other folder you open for the first time should
>   also inherit those settings.

[Source (Apple Discussion)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4237578)